# Count in .fpr file generated does not match with count generated using FPRUtility command on the same fpr file

Tags: fortify, sca

In my Jenkins job, FPR file is generated after running the scan on particular build of code. If I download the FPR file and open it using SCA workbench it shows me the following count : Critical-0, High-0, Medium-0 and Low-313.

But when i run the below FPR utility command on the same fpr file using Command Line I get the count as follows : Critical-2, High-7, Medium-0 and Low-314.

Below is the command that I ran -

FPRUtility -[myfprfilename].fpr -information -search -query "[fortify priority order]:critical"
FPRUtility -[myfprfilename].fpr -information -search -query "[fortify priority order]:high"
FPRUtility -[myfprfilename].fpr -information -search -query "[fortify priority order]:medium"
FPRUtility -[myfprfilename].fpr -information -search -query "[fortify priority order]:low"

Initially I thought it is showing count of suppressed and hidden issues so in FPR file, under option I check marked show suppressed and show hidden issues, but still the count does not matched with count displayed by FPRUtility command.

I wan to know how are we getting the extra count and what can I do to remove the extra issues count?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is a filter issue, maybe there is a default filter set on your AuditWorkbench hiding the raw issue counts.